# Django/Celery: max_retries works for re-try, but printed value is always the Celery default (3)

Tags: celery, django-celery

```
    @app.task(bind=True, autoretry_for=(Exception,), retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 10, 'countdown': 5})
    def job_deliver_message(self, message_id):
        print('Try {0}/{1}'.format(self.request.retries, self.max_retries))
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

To test, I'm causing this task to fail on purpose. it DOES re-try 10 times!, however, the printout is like:

```
[2020-06-03 19:14:06,700: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] Try 0/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:12,080: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Try 1/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:17,553: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Try 2/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:23,000: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-5] Try 3/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:28,489: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] Try 4/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:33,603: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] Try 5/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:39,038: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-11] Try 6/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:44,525: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-13] Try 7/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:49,688: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] Try 8/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:54,985: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Try 9/3
[2020-06-03 19:14:54,985: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Try 10/3
```

What am I missing? am I printing the value for the `max_retries` from the wrong place?

and Yes: I do know i can just show the "10"... as I explicitly set it... but just wanted to know why it's giving me 3 when it's given 10 and actually acting upon it for the number of re-tries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' ve implemented retry slighthly differnt i.e. i have following celery task in one of my projects:

```
@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=4, default_retry_delay=3)
def get_external_sentence_translation(self, translation_request):
    """
       Passing translation data to translator
    :param self
    :param translation_request:
    :return:
    """

    url = settings.TRANSLATOR_BULK_TRANSLATION_RESOURCE
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        result = session.post(url=url, data=translation_request)
        if result.status_code == 500:
            self.retry()
        result_json = result.json(encoding='utf-8')
        # print (u'json: ' + json.dumps(result_json))
        if 'status' not in result_json:
            message = 'Auto translation in get_external_sentence_translation json status is undefined'
            logger.warning(message)
            raise RuntimeError(message)
        if 'result' not in result_json and result_json['status'] is False:
            message = 'Auto translation in get_external_sentence_translation json status is False'
            logger.warning(message)
            raise RuntimeError(message)
        session.close()
        if 'result' in result_json:
            validation_result = JsonEncoder.from_json(result_json['result'])
            return validation_result # result_json[u'result']
            return result_json
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Raised exception in get_external_sentence_translation')
        logger.error(e)
        try:
            raise self.retry()
        except MaxRetriesExceededError:
            return BulkTranslationDto(status='False').to_json()
```

here i'm manually call retry() and catch MaxRetriesExceededError to stop retrying

Answer (score 1):

You are using `self.max_retries` which is set to 3 by default.

The retry method has another variable `max_retries` which is set to 10 in this case.

Code reference: [task.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/task.py#L681)

Answer (score 0):

> am I printing the value for the `max_retries` from the wrong place?

I think this could be the source of the issue.  Can you delve into the Celery source and / or set breakpoints?

You could try setting `max_retries` in a [class-based task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions) and see if you get a different result:

```py
class BaseTaskWithRetry(Task):
    autoretry_for = (Exception,)
    retry_kwargs = {'max_retries': 5}
```